# How do I get my threads to run in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I am able to call class instances fine with my code but can't seem to get it to multithread. It just looks like the threads don't start, even though they are alive.

I have read the documentation on threading, tried using super(), etc.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread

class Dashboard(Thread):

    def __init__(self, position, url):
        super().__init__()       
        self.position = position
        self.url = url

    def instance(self):

        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=2560,1600')
        chrome_options.add_argument(self.position)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get(self.url)

screen1 = Dashboard('--window-position=1000,1000', 'https://www.facebook.com')
screen2 = Dashboard('--window-position=1,1', 'https://www.youtube.com')

screen1.start()
print(screen1.is_alive)
screen2.start()
print(screen2.is_alive)
```

The output is:

```
<bound method Thread.is_alive of <Dashboard(Thread-1, stopped 123145347162112)>>
<bound method Thread.is_alive of <Dashboard(Thread-2, stopped 123145347162112)>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving any arguments to the superclass constructor, meaning the target is `None`.

Assuming the `instance()` method is what you want to get executed when you call `screen1.start()`, try this:

```
super().__init__(target=self.instance)
```

Also, you probably want to call the `is_alive`, method, rather than printing its signature.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `is_alive` method:

```
 print(screen1.is_alive())
```

Also you don't override `run` in your `Thread` subclass `Dashboard` so when `start` is called they do nothing. Perhaps you wanted `instance` to run if that is so then name it `run`:

```
def run(self):
```

Or have `run` call it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just had to rename def instance: to def run: